# Where can I find a detailed documentation for the Instapaper API?

Tags: api, web-applications

I have already read the [Instapaper API page](http://www.instapaper.com/api), but it only explains how to:

- Authenticate a user.
- Add an article to read later.

What I would like is information to programmatically:

- Retrieve a list of the articles in the "Read Later" list.
- Archive, favourite, put in a folder, delete a given article from the list.
- Create and delete folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a public API available yet, that would give you the functionality you're requesting.

According to this [interview](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/10/instapaper-marco-arment/all/1) with Marco Arment, the creator of Instapaper, he plans to extend his API in the future:

> "[...] I do intend to make a fully
>   featured API available soon that would
>   enable third-party developers to make
>   Instapaper clients if they wish.”

**Update:**
In the meanwhile, Marco Arment has made the full Instapaper API [available](http://blog.instapaper.com/post/3208433429). The only restriction is, that the API can only used by paid-subscriber accounts (currently 1$/month).

Comment: Ah. That would mean that my current app for Instapaper (Everpaper) probably works - at least partially - by scraping HTML. Thank you for the reply and the link.

Comment: Don't know how Everpaper works internally. Maybe the developer got some support by Marco himself (see http://www.marco.org/about).